# WPF Listbox multi selection working like windows files select

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selection

Is it possible in a WPF `ListBox` with selection mode "Multiple" working like windows files folder. If one row of the `Listbox` is selected if I click on another row it automatically deselect the previous one.  Also if the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key is pressed it allows me to select multiple rows and same with the <kbd>shift</kbd> key, just simulating the windows files folder.

What are the events and properties are required for this?  Any code shared will do wonder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `ListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Extended`. It will allow you to select multiple items using Shift and Ctrl key.

MSDN reference
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionmode.aspx

Comment: Working awesome.One thing more how to deselect all the selected rows on single mouse click if clicked on empty listbox item area.

Comment: Listbox.UnselectAll() will remove all the selections,I required event which can be fired for this.